# Why am I getting different results if my css is typed into head or linked to .css file?

Tags: html, css

I am a beginner and have the following problem:

When I insert css directly into the head of my .html file, I get a great result:
[typed into the head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YJ6NG.jpg)

But when I link my .css file into the head, the very first word ("Holy") does not show up properly, as follows:
[Linked into the Head](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QYvH2.jpg)

I have looked it over to ensure the css is the same whether pasted or linked, and I am currently at a loss. Any insight would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

This is the css:

```
<span class="holy"></span>
<span class="waiving"></span>
<span class="american"></span>
<span class="flag"></span>
<span class="batman"></span>

<style>
  .holy {
    background-color: red;
    color: white;
  }
  .waiving {
    background-color: white;
    color: blue;
  }
  .american {
    background-color: blue;
    color: white;
  }
  .flag {
    background-color: white;
    color: red;
  }
  .batman {
    background-color: black;
    color: yellow;
  }
</style>
```

This is is how I linked it when only the First "Holy" does not work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="batman_with_css.css">
</head>

<body>
  <span class="holy">Holy</span>
  <span class="waiving">Waiving</span>
  <span class="american">American</span>
  <span class="flag">Flag</span>
  <span class="batman">Batman!!!</span>
  <br>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/af/7b/d3/af7bd3df85c1397456084b29e3729269--keaton-batman-batman-car.jpg">

</body>
<html>
```

And this is the html file with the css in the head where everyything including the first word "Holy" does work:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <span class="holy"></span>
  <span class="waiving"></span>
  <span class="american"></span>
  <span class="flag"></span>
  <span class="batman"></span>

  <style>
    .holy {
      background-color: red;
      color: white;
    }
    .waiving {
      background-color: white;
      color: blue;
    }
    .american {
      background-color: blue;
      color: white;
    }
    .flag {
      background-color: white;
      color: red;
    }
    .batman {
      background-color: black;
      color: yellow;
    }
  </style>

</head>
<body>
  <span class="holy">Holy</span>
  <span class="waiving">Waiving</span>
  <span class="american">American</span>
  <span class="Flag">Flag</span>
  <span class="batman">Batman!!!</span>
  <br>
  <img src="https://i.pinimg.com/736x/af/7b/d3/af7bd3df85c1397456084b29e3729269--keaton-batman-batman-car.jpg">
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You most likely missed a `.` for `.holly`.

Comment: Is there an easy way to post the css on this thread. @Adriani6, I made sure the css was the same for both the linked and the typed in versions. I actually cut and pasted the css from the head of the one that worked and into the .css file I linked

Comment: @casbonano Best thing to do would be creating a JSFiddle with the said issue. There is a code formatting tag you can use to paste your code into your question. Just make sure you edit the question and not post an answer.

Comment: @adriani6 thanks for that help. I have edited the original post to include the code.

Comment: HTML elements don't belong in `<head>`

Comment: @jhpratt I see. Thank you very much. That now makes sense.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not supposed to put in HTML code in stylesheets, which you did by adding those span elements at the top.
*Change your CSS file so it looks like this.....*

```
  .holy {
background-color: red;
color: white;
}
.waiving {
background-color: white;
color: blue;
}
.american {
background-color: blue;
color: white;
}
.flag {
background-color: white;
color: red;
}
.batman {
background-color: black;
color: yellow;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide an explanation of what this does?

Comment: I am sorry, @Mohammed, but I do not understand what you are suggesting I do. Are you telling me to make the code look like the code you posted?

Comment: @jhpratt In the original post I added 2 photos of the code previewed in Atom, both the linked and typed into the head css. This is my first time here so if clicking on those image links does not work please let me know. The only difrerence in both outcomes is that in one the first word correctly has a red background with white font, while the second example the first word does not

Comment: @casbonano Not sure why you're pinging me in on that comment.

Comment: @Mohammed Thank you. That was it. Much appreciated.